# Alternative for goto in c programming

Tags: c, goto

Is there any alternative for goto statement in c programming.

Actually i am planning to make one new simulator for my application. For this simulator i need to go particular place again and again inside main from some other function. Goto only works with in the functions otherwise it won't work. Can any one suggest me any other alternative methods.

Thanks advance.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: There's `setjmp()` and `longjmp()` if you're feeling kinky...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Separate your `main` into functions. Instead of jumping to a location inside `main`, execute an appropriate function. That might require passing some parameters to the functions but it surely worth it.

Comment: But I plan for more than 30 place by goto statements so i think goto may be the best option. Instead of creating 30 functions for that only i asked alternate for goto pls suggest me thanks for your previous ans.

Comment: @Jeyamaran First, 30 functions is a sensible amount, depending on the actual requirements. Second, I almost sure that difference between these 30 funcs is mostly in the processed data - this number can easily shrink to much less by utilizing parameters that will generalize the data.

Comment: thanks this may be best option. @icepack

Answer (score 4):

You can use your own functions and call it whenever you need it.

Comment: But I plan for more than 30 place by goto statements so i think goto may be the best option. Instead of creating 30 functions for that only i asked alternate for goto pls suggest.

Comment: @Jeyamaran goto is never the best option and often is the worst.

Comment: Breaking down your program in small functional units is a good practice.

Comment: ohh k. but its just simulator so only i plan for goto. I too know goto may collaps our functionlity. try to go for function.

Comment: @Jeyamaran; That would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Put "the place you need to go to" inside a function and call that function every time you need.

Of course that function will have its own scope and can't access variables from the calling point.

So you'll need to pass the required data to the function or make use (discouraged) of globals

Answer (score 0):

> For this simulator i need to go particular place again and again inside main from some other function.

This can quickly lead to spaghetti code. `goto` within a function to jump *forward*, for example into cleanup code, has it's fair uses. Jumping between functions: Don't do this, this is horrible (technically it can be done with some helpers which I'm not going to name here, to keep the temptation from you).

So what you try to do sounds a lot like so called *coroutines* to me. And that can be done with C, by utilizing some construct called "*Duff's Device*". There's a nice article about it here: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/coroutines.html

And then there's a C coroutine library on Google Code: https://code.google.com/p/libconcurrency/